# I'm working at laravel project but there is always that error : ErrorException Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

this is my candidatController.php
the error is in the line before the last line(`$prev_canditure->etat="archifé";`)

```
$candidat_nw=Candidat::orderby('created_at','DESC')->first();
$prev_canditure=Candidature::where('candidat_id','=',$candidat->id)->orderby('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

$prev_canditure->etat = "Archivé";
$prev_canditure->save();
```

Comment: That means `Candidature::where(..)` returned `null`…?!

Comment: I don't have any idea about that ! so what is the solution

Comment: _"so what is the solution"_ - hard to say, because you neglected to tell us what actually needs to be _achieved_ there in the first place. If your script can successfully proceed without modifying any candidate at this point - then wrap the last two lines into `if($prev_canditure) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code you can use a defensive code approach by checking if the query will return null

```
$candidat_nw=Candidat::orderby('created_at','DESC')->first();
$prev_canditure=Candidature::where('candidat_id','=',$candidat->id)->orderby('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

if (!(empty($prev_candidature))){
$prev_canditure->etat = "Archivé";
$prev_canditure->save();

}
```

Comment: `empty` is  superfluous here and will only needlessly suppress typo errors. Just `if ($prev_candidature)` will do just fine. Your `!` is also misplaced…

Comment: thanks! that's worked bro :)